# Quick one: Finding a specific allocated object in my class

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I feel stupid for asking this. But in a class, I alloc an ASIHTTPRequest. This is done in the implementation alone, not the interface, since it's an autoreleased object.

I am not sure sure how to cancel this request. I have the following:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in ???????) {
     [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Basically, I am not sure where and what in my class to look for to find the request that's currently running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your request somewhere, i.e. in an ivar.

Comment: And what if I don't want to? :(

Comment: Easy - if you don't store it somewhere, you won't be able to find it. What's so bad about storing it?